# req.file.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

I keep getting the error req.file.map is not a function. This is the code below

```
router.post("/", upload.single("tutorial"), function(req, res){
var tutorial    = req.file;
    };
    var newCourse = {
        tutorial: `/course_uploads/${req.file.filename}`, 
    }
    Course.create(newCourse, function(err, newlyCreated){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            //redirect it page back to the courses page
            res.redirect("courses/" + req.body.course);
        }
    });    
});
```

Comment: Your code isn't valid. Could you please fix it up

Comment: Also, you're using `upload.single()`. Why would `req.file` be an array? Did you mean to use `upload.array("tutorial")` an `req.files` instead? See https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#arrayfieldname-maxcount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**upload.single** uploads only one file. If you think req.file is a array, well it's not. It's an object because you uploaded single file. Remove the map functions and write this for uploading single file.

```
var tutorial = `/uploads/${req.file.filename}`
```